# My linkedlist print function goes into infinite loop

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

linkedlist.h

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H_
#define LINKEDLIST_H_

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class list{
public:
    list();
    class node;
    typedef T           value_type;
    typedef T&          reference;
    typedef node        node_type;
    typedef node_type*  node_pointer;

    list&           push_back(value_type);
    value_type      pop_front();
    node_pointer    begin() const;
private:
    node_pointer    head, tail;
};


template <typename T>
class list<T>::node{
public:
    node(value_type value = 0);
    void            setData(value_type);
    value_type      getData() const;
    void            setNext(node_pointer);
    node_pointer    getNext() const;

private:
    value_type      data;
    node_pointer    ptr_next;
};

template <typename T>
inline list<T>::node::node(value_type value) : data(value), ptr_next(nullptr){
}

template <typename T>
void list<T>::node::setData(value_type value){
    this->data = value;
}

template <typename T>
typename list<T>::value_type        list<T>::node::getData() const{
    return this->data;
}

template <typename T>
void list<T>::node::setNext(node_pointer ptr){
    this->ptr_next = ptr;
}

template <typename T>
typename list<T>::node_pointer  list<T>::node::getNext() const{
    return this->ptr_next;
}

template <typename T>
list<T>::list() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr){

}

template <typename T>
list<T>&    list<T>::push_back(value_type value){
    node_pointer item = new node_type(value);
    if(this->tail) this->tail->setNext(item);
    this->tail = item;
    if(!this->head) this->head = this->tail;

    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
typename list<T>::value_type    list<T>::pop_front(){
    if(this->head){
        node_pointer    item = this->head;
        value_type      value = this->head->getData();

        this->head = this->head->getNext();
        delete item;

        return value;
    }

return 0;
}

template <typename T>
typename list<T>::node_pointer list<T>::begin() const{
    return this->head;
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &stream, list<T> &obj){
    typename list<T>::node_pointer ptr = obj.begin();
    while(ptr->getNext() != nullptr){
        stream << ptr->getData() << " ";
        ptr->setNext(ptr->getNext());
    }
    return stream;
}

#endif /* LINKEDLIST_H_ */
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main (int argc, char ** argv){ 

    list<int> mylist;

    mylist.push_back(5).push_back(1);

    cout << mylist;


    return 0;
}
```

I just wanted to create a print function which overloads `operator<<`. whatever i did, i couldn't find the solution. What is the wrong with this overloaded operator<< function? And how can i clean garbage if program throws error. How destructor function should be?

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code, with a debugger?

Comment: Yes then i got the mistake i made.

Comment: What do you expect this line to do? `ptr->setNext(ptr->getNext());`

Comment: you are right. :/

Comment: @RıfatTolgaKiran So, why did you use debugger, to resolve the problem that you were having, **before** posting on SO, not **after**, if you couldn't find the problem with debugging?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I am new to debuging. at the first look i couldnt find what the mistake was . Later on i realized that i was stepping wrong. I have solved first problem. But my second question remains as it is.

Comment: @RıfatTolgaKiran -- That's strange that you're "new to debugging", but the code you wrote basically requires you to know how to use the debugger.  There is no way you can learn or write template code without knowing basic debugging skills.  I would expect "new to debugging" to be associated with people who are totally new to programming in general, and are barely past the "Hello World" stage, not in such an advanced stage such as templates.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i know basic concepts of debuging such as step in, step over etc. actually i dont have the command of debuging at all. For instance i still cant understand if there is memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &stream, list<T> &obj){
    typename list<T>::node_pointer ptr = obj.begin();
    while(ptr != nullptr){
        stream << ptr->getData() << " ";
        ptr = ptr->getNext();
    }
    return stream;
}
```

i realized that i made a logical mistake during the print function. But i still wonder how to collect garbage?

Comment: Question in an answer? Is the question rhetorical?